# How to show that $a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{(z-c)^{n+1}}dz$ in Laurent series?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I would appreciate if anyone can help me with this question.

My attempt: Let $f(z)=\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty a_m(z-c)^m$. I divided both sides by $(z-c)^{n+1}$ to get $$\frac{f(z)}{(z-c)^{n+1}}=\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty a_m(z-c)^{m-n-1}.$$ But, since $\gamma$ is a closed curve in $A$ we have for $m\neq n$, $$\int_\gamma a_m(z-c)^{m-n-1}dz=0.$$

This gives $$\int_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{(z-c)^{n+1}}=0$$ and so I am stuck.

[image]

Comment: "We have for $m \neq n$"; and what happens for $m = n$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, I see. We will get $\frac{f(z)}{(z-c)^{n+1}}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n(z-c)^{-1}$. So, we can parametrise $\gamma$ and get the value of the integrand $\int_\gamma (z-c)^{-1}dz$. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you just typo'ed or whether you're misunderstanding something. What you wrote is not correct. But it bears some resemblance to the correct stuff, so it may just be mistyped.

Comment: @DanielFischer I didn't mistyped. Why my comment is not correct?

Comment: The series for $\frac{f(z)}{(z-c)^{n+1}}$ that you have in the question body is correct, and that series differs from the one in your comment, the series in the comment, if it converges, gives a function of the form $\frac{A}{z-c}$, and generally, $\frac{f(z)}{(z-c)^{n+1}}$ is not of that form.

Comment: @DanielFischer Was my typo that I didn't include the integrals, like this $\int_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{(z-c)^{n+1}}=a_n\int_\gamma(z-c)^{-1}$?

Comment: Aha. If that was what you meant, that is correct - if you add the $dz$ to the integrals. And now you only need to know the value of $\int_{\gamma} (z-c)^{-1}\,dz$.